# Secure Boot Violation after moving my Ubuntu UEFI SSD into identical laptop

Tags: uefi, secure-boot

Recently my old laptop (about 8 years old) with Lubuntu installed on a UEFI SSD died. It just refused to start at all, the little led that normally lights when the mains is on also did not light up. I measured the output of the charger and this was normal, also after opening the laptop the battery seemed to be normal. I concluded that something in the power circuit in the laptop broke down.

Happily I was able to buy an identical (unused!) laptop and I inserted the SSD that I removed from the dead laptop into it.

During boot I received a message: "Secure Boot Violation, Invalid signature detected. Check Secure Boot Policy in Setup."

After disabling the Secure Boot option in the UEFI-BIOS, it booted normally and I was back into my Lubuntu as always.

Question 1: How dangerous is it to use that laptop with the disabled Secure Boot?

Question 2: Is there a way to have Secure Boot enabled and boot normally ?

Question 3: In the UEFI-BIOS the option below the Secure Boot, gives the possibility to "delete all secure boot variables" I include[image] a picture of this option. My question is, is it possible to use this to boot normally with Secure Boot enabled?

EDIT:
I had no clue that my OS-release could have anything to do with the message of Secure Boot Violation.

```
$ lsb_release -a
No LSB modules are available.
Distributor ID: Ubuntu
Description:    Ubuntu 22.04.3 LTS
Release:        22.04
Codename:       jammy
```

Updating made no difference, the message kept coming up.

EDIT-2:

```
$ dpkg -l shim-signed
Gevraagd=(U)onbekend/(I)nstalleren/ve(R)wijderen/(P)wissen/(H)ouden
| Status=Niet/Inst/Conf/Uitgep/halF-geconf/Halfgeïnst/verWacht-trig/Trig-bezig
|/ Fout?=(geen)/heRinst. nodig/ (Status,Fout: hoofdletter=ernstig)
||/ Naam           Versie               Architectuur Omschrijving
+++-==============-====================-============-==============================================================
ii  shim-signed    1.51.3+15.7-0ubuntu1 amd64        Secure Boot chain-loading bootloader (Microsoft-signed binary)
```

Comment: You might need the signed versions of shim, grub, and kernel for secure boot to work.  Unless you have hardware requiring proprietary drivers (unsigned, so can't use secure boot), Ubuntu really doesn't care.

Comment: What release of that Lubuntu system, has it been upgraded? so its not using *revoked* SHIM? Your release details are where I'd start, and we won't know that unless told.

Comment: @ubfan1: I am not familiar with details of shim, grub and kernel. What can I do to get signed version of these?

Comment: @guiverc: I added an edit in my question to show which release of Lubuntu I have. I have no clue about a revoked SHIM.

Comment: The grub and shim signed packages have "signed" in their names, the kernel packages are signed unless they have "unsigned" in their names. sudo apt install grub-efi-amd64-signed  to install the signed grub version, etc. Maybe best to uninstall the unsigned one too.

Comment: @ubfan1: thank you for the suggestions, but what may be obvious to you, it is not for me. I could give the terminal command you are suggesting, but what about "etc."? And how do I uninstall the unsigned version (of grub?)? Is there any risk in installing/uninstalling these things at all?

Comment: Please add the output of dpkg -l shim-signed to your posting to see if you have shim-signed and what version.  The revoked versions are less than 15.4 (in the name, mine's ...+15.7...) I think you must have a signed shim for a 2015 Lubuntu install, but if not, that's a problem. Always backup before system changes, and have an install media available to boot to recover from bootloader problems.

Comment: @ubfan1: I added the output of dpkg -l shim-signed to my question under EDIT-2

Comment: @plopper, I would not bother to fix secure boot. If you want a high level of privacy of your data, you should have 'encrypted disk': use LVM with encryption and you should keep your Lubuntu software up to date and generally be cautious when browsing the internet. I think that is more important than secure boot.